# Prevent Airport Utility from Opening Automatically

Tags: network, wifi, airport

My computer is connected to a (non-Airport) wifi network and is working properly.

However, someone else in my building uses an Airport. Every few hours, Airport Utility opens, and shows me this other network, as if I wanted to configure it. Is there some way I can either forget this Airport device, or disable Airport Utility from automatically opening?

OS X 10.10.5, Retina Macbook Pro 13".

Answer (score 1):

Open AirPort utility and then open the preferences window.

Deselect the option to monitor base stations or select the option to only monitor base stations that you have set up.

Comment: I've tried that. Now I'll just have to wait it out...

Comment: ...and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the Airport base station agent

```
launchctl remove com.apple.AirPortBaseStationAgent
```

Comment: This did not work on Catalina.

Comment: I'm having similar problems with a 2012 MacBook Pro on Catalina. I'd love to be able to disable the newer version of Airport Utility so that I can set up an older AirPort Express Base Station (A1392)